# Leaflet Awesome Markers - Balloons not showing

Tags: javascript, leaflet, font-awesome

This is actually rather strange.

I'm new to this library, so I don't know if anything has changed and the tutorial is outdated.

When I do this:

```
L.marker([51.344853, 0.098877]).addTo(mymap);
```

The default blue balloon marker shows.

If I do this:

```
var redMarker = L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({
        icon: 'coffee',
        iconColor: 'black',
        prefix: 'fa',
        markerColor: 'red'
});
L.marker([51.344853, 0.098877], {icon: redMarker}).addTo(mymap);
```

I expect a red balloon to show, along with a coffee icon. But what I'm getting is the coffee icon alone and no balloon.

Please, is there something else I'm supposed to be setting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you forgot to attach some dependencies. Did you remember to add links to font-awesome and Leaflet.awesome-markers css and js files?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Leaflet.awesome-markers/2.0.2/leaflet.awesome-markers.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Leaflet.awesome-markers/2.0.2/leaflet.awesome-markers.js"></script>
```

Please check out the working pen example:

https://codepen.io/dagmara223/pen/BpqdZm

Comment: Thanks! Turns out I wasn't referencing the right dependencies. Also, I a couple of files in the dist/images were corrupt. Thanks so much!